# How to open a URL path pdf in Flexpaper Annotation viewer?

Tags: c#, asp.net, flexpaper

How to open a PDF file from remotely hosted application.I need to enable the CORS(cross origin request Sharing)in the server . But i don't know how to enable in flex-paper annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You enable CORS by making sure your server sends the following response headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
Access-Control-Allow-Methods:GET
Access-Control-Allow-Origin:http://www.yourdomain.com
```